# Existe algun Plugins para hacer sistemas con formularios autogestionables en laravel o php?

Tags: php, laravel, formularios

Buenos dias, la consulta es especifica, conocen algún plugin, librería o algo que se le parezca para realizar crud autogestionables desde el backend, es decir, para crear un aplicación que las personas puedan personalizar sus formularios para que sean usados posteriormente? Perdonen si me explico, busque en internet pero no encuentro formular la pregunta bien.

Answer (score 1):

como no te refieras a algo como esto, no se que decirte : http://labs.infyom.com

Comment: Revisare pero nose si sea lo que necesito, tratare de explicarme un poco mas, lo que necesito es que los usuarios pueda agregar campos, es decir formularios a traves de la aplicacion...

Comment: Este tipo de preguntas no son bienvenidas, por lo cual sugerimos no responderlas, gracias.